# Listing names of available Virtualbox VMs using Python

Tags: python, virtualbox

How do I list the names of available VirtualBox virtual machines with **[pyvb](http://code.google.com/p/pyvb/)** modules?

Answer (score 4):

A good resource to learn VBox Python API is read the implementation of [vboxweb](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/)

For your specific question, you can take a look at line 289 of [VBoxWebSrv.py](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/source/browse/branches/VBox-3.0/VBoxWebSrv.py) to see how virtual machines are populated.

In a nut shell, the code could be like below:

```
import vboxapi 
virtualBoxManager = vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager(None, None) 
vbox = virtualBoxManager.vbox
vboxVMList=virtualBoxManager.getArray(vbox, 'machines')
```

Comment: tested this code on my machine and it worked perfectly (ubuntu 9.10 x64 - VirtualBox 3.0.12)

Comment: I tried this, and got this as output, any ideas?
[<XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>, <XPCOM component '<unknown>' (implementing IMachine)>]

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer from Findekano, I will add the last line:

```
import vboxapi 
virtualBoxManager = vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager(None, None) 
vbox = virtualBoxManager.vbox
vboxVMList = virtualBoxManager.getArray(vbox, 'machines')
vboxNameList = [mach.name for mach in vboxVMList]
```